# This fact makes the Korean language much simpler than English is

Tags: parallelism, comparative

My sentences:
**(1a)** *Bob read more books than Fred*. — We compare two nouns: "*Bob*" and "*Fred*".
**(1b)** *Bob read more books than Fred did*. — We compare two phrases: "*Bob read*" and "*Fred did*".

Sentences from [here](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/this-fact-makes-the-language-simpler-than-does-english.2289034/):
**(2a)** *This fact makes the Korean language much simpler than English*. — We compare two noun phrases: "*the Korean language*" and "*English*".
**(2b)** *This fact makes the Korean language much simpler than English **is***. — We compare two phrases: **X** and "*English is*".

I can't find the parallelism in (2b) and, therefore, I can't understand the method by which (2b) was made up. Could you tell me please what **X** is equal to?

Comment: As FumbleFingers said of your previous question, "this question looks like a pointless exercise." The addition of **did** in the first sentence and of **is** in the second don't alter the meaning of either. The sentences are more elegant without the added word. Meaning and elegance might be more important to a language-learner than parallelism.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian I can't understand your logic. You go by the sentence "this question looks like a pointless exercise." But "pointless" to whom? Obvious, if I asked it, to me it's not pointless.

Comment: Your logic is incorrect. Sentence 1a does not compare "Bob" and "Fred". Furthermore, parallelism is not required in comparisons with "than". Are you getting this information from somewhere, and if so, where?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan This information was created by me in an attempt to understand the algorithm of building sentences with "than". "_Sentence 1a does not compare "Bob" and "Fred"._" - could you tell me why? Thanks.

Comment: The title doesn't reflect the sense of the question. It sounds like a newspaper headline sensation to me

Comment: There isn 't parallelism . Language isn't what somebody thinks it should be, or what somebody makes up rules for, but what people actaually say - and if the rules don't account for that, then the rules are incomplete or wrong. Having said that, I find 2b to be awkward, and I would not intentionally say (or write) it myself. But I'm not surprised that some people do.

Comment: I'm not sure that Korean *is* simpler than English, but it all depends on what each individual thinks "simpler" is!  :^)

Comment: @Loviii Because it compares the amount of books that they read, not the people (at least directly). Note that the comparitive adjective ("more") modifies "books".

Comment: 2 compares the simplicity of English and Korean, but it describes a situation that changes the simplicity of Korean without affecting the simplicity of English. But the "is" on the end is optional, because it's implied if it isn't present.

Answer (score 1):

In (2a), *English* stands for *the English language,* so the sentence directly compares two languages. The poster on WordReference doesn't say that (2b) is better than (2a), only better than the other version suggested by the questioner.

I was always taught that (1b) was the strictly correct version, although of course (1a) is perfectly acceptable in everyday conversation. The sentence compares the number of books read by Bob with the number read by Fred, not with Fred himself.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer my question.

I think we can add "*be*" to "(2a)" & "(2b)":
(2a) + be: *This fact makes the Korean language **be** much simpler than English*.
(2b) + be: *This fact makes the Korean language **be** much simpler than English **is***.

Therefore, there is parallelism between "*the Korean language be*" and "*English is*".